# How to run a gui C++ executable on startup in ubuntu?

Tags: linux

I have to run a wxWidgets GUI C++ executable with root user on startup of ubuntu. Desktop entry method is running but with current logged in user. `/etc/init.d` script does not run gui application.

Please tell me the exact way how to run the application if someone knows.

Comment: As root? _Why?_

Comment: the library i am using needs super user permissions

Comment: Well yes, but still why? What does it do? Does it access something in /dev? (If so, what specifically?)

Comment: it do auditing.